# When Theme install I get an error:This script can not be ran with Administrative Privileges

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, gnome, themes

Dialog msg-->then try again.You may need to reboot.installation will now abort...
This script can not be ran with Administrative Privileges. The script elevates on its own. Please run the script with Standard User Privileges. Installation will now Abort.
Help Me.
(as root
sh GUIInstall.sh)
Help Me..

Answer (score 1):

First I would be extremely careful here. You should not need to run a script, let alone with root privileges, to install a theme.

I understand, scripts such as this can seem "easy" if you are new to Themes, but, this is how social engineering works as well.

Here is a great tutorial on installing themes:

[Install themes and icons in Ubuntu 11.10](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-GNOME-Themes-in-Ubuntu-11-10-231213.shtml)

With that caution in mind, the error message seems to imply the script will elevate on it's own.

```
chmod a+x GUIInstall.sh
./GUIInstall.sh
```

If you have a problem with that, I would ask you pastebin the entire script and paste a link back here so we can both look at what it is doing and if it need to be modified in some way.

good luck.

EDIT: Added a snipit

```
if [[ $UID -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script can not be ran with Administrative Privileges. The script elevates on its own. Please run the script with Standard User Privileges."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank YOu very Much...BUT  I have still user Root..and  Did Not installation aborted .

Comment: You would have to post the script. Some scripts test if you are running as a user or root, and act accordingly, I will post a snipit

Comment: .themes files a Folder in Desktop...GUIInstall.sh,Core.py vs..

Comment: GUIInstall.sh file in ------>if [[ "$PYTHON" =~ "2.7" ]] || [[ "$PYTHON" =~ "2.6" ]] || [[ "$PYTHON" =~ "2.5" ]] || [[ "$PYTHON" =~ "2.4" ]]  || [[ $UID -eq 0 ]]; then
   python Core.py "$SWITCH"
   echo "This script can not be ran with Administrative Privileges. The script elevates on its own. Please run the script with Standard User Privileges."
  exit 1
else
   zenity --error --text="$WORD1 $PYTHON. $WORD2"
   python Core.py "$SWITCH"


fi

exit

Comment: so run the script as a user, without sudo, what happens ?

Comment: # Initializing Win2-7 Installer...                              [  OK  ]
# Initializing Language Support...                              [  OK  ]
# Initializing Python Modules...                                [  OK  ]
# Initializing Variables...                                     [  OK  ]
# Initializing Functions...                                     [  OK  ]
# Detecting Processes...                                        [  OK  ]
# Detecting Access Level...                                     [ FAIL ]
# Installation Aborted!...
# 
# Please Press [ ENTER ] To Close

Comment: Looks like a buggy script. Either post the entire script in a pastebin, contact the author, or use an alternate method to install your theme.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be administrator for installation. Login as administrator by using comand `sudo -s` and enter your password and then try again. I hope it will work.

Comment: I have still user Root..and But Did Not installation aborted ..themes files a Folder in Desktop...GUIInstall.sh,Core.py vs..